# Angular required select option not working for placeholder

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

[plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/eCaAS07AvpF2Fp61Prxb?p=preview)

I have a default select value properly not fulfilling the required validation:

```
<form name="testForm" novalidate>
  <select ng-model="model.selecter" required ng-options="opt for opt in options">
    <option value="">Select One</option>
  </select>
</form>

$scope.options = [
    'First',
    'Second',
    'Third'
];
```

While "Select One" is selected, `testForm.$valid` is `false`, as it should be.

However, I would like to be able to add my placeholder to the options array as well, but in this instance it marks it as valid.

```
<form name="testForm" novalidate>
  <select ng-model="model.selecter" required ng-options="opt for opt in options">
  </select>
</form>

$scope.options = [
    'Select One',
    'First',
    'Second',
    'Third'
];

$scope.model = { selecter: $scope.options[0] }; // sets the default selected option
```

Here `testForm.$valid` is always `true`.  Is there any way to make my `Select One` option not fulfill the `required` status of the form?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are trying to complicate something that works, but if you must you will have to make some other changes as well.
Change your select to be like this

```
             <select ng-model="model2.selecter" required ng-options="opt.value as opt.label for opt in options2">
             </select>
```

And your values to be like this

```
      $scope.options2 = [
        {label:'Select One',value:''},
        {label:'First',value:'1'}
      ];
```

And do not give your model variable a value. Make it blank.

```
         $scope.model2 = { 
            selecter: ''
        };
```

Comment: Agree about unnecessarily complicating something that works as designed.

Comment: @Scott I have a lot of these dropdowns that have different options based on the context they're loaded in, so the options can change.  I suppose I could create a directive to handle all this, but it just seemed this was the easiest way if the first one could simply always be non-valid.